# How can I allow subscriptions on RedwoodJS?

Tags: redwoodjs

Let's say I create a new RedwoodJS project from scratch with

```
yarn create redwood-app my-project
```

In this step, I've chosen to create a Typescript project... Then I setup this project to use both the experimental server and realtime features:

```
yarn rw exp setup-server-file
yarn rw exp setup-realtime
```

And finally, I create a new subscription:

```
yarn rw exp generate-realtime mySub
```

[image]

So far it seems to be working fine and I get the following result:

[image]

However, if I now start this project with `yarn rw dev` and go to the graphiql endpoint on `http://localhost:8911/graphql`, the suggested subscription query on my code doesn't work, if I try to run

```
subscription ListenToMysubChannel {
  listenToMysubChannel(id: "1") {
    body
    from
  }
}
```

I get the error:

```json
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "GraphQL operation type \"subscription\" is not allowed.",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 1,
          "column": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

What am I missing in this procedure? Do I need to manually edit any file in order to activate the GraphQL subscriptions?

Answer (score 0):

Bit of a stab but maybe you've missed this step:
https://redwoodjs.com/docs/realtime#graphql-configuration

Specifically: uncommenting the 'realtime' at the end of api/server.ts.